# JSF HEAD request handling

Tags: jsf

What does JSF (different for 1.2 and 2.2?) do when a HEAD request arrives on a URL? It seems like the complete view is created and all backing beans are enabled just like a normal request.
I just can't find the specs for this and so can't guarantee the behavior.
Does anybody know the flow through the phases when a HEAD request arrives at the JSF servlet?

I'm thinking of using a filter to capture HEAD requests and return without invoking the rest of the chain. Any ideas about that?